# How to sampling 5000 rows from dataframe which satisfy a condition in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe `df` with a column `v1`. `v1` can takes three values:0, 1 or 2.

I want to select random 5000 rows from `df` where `v1 == 0` and 5000 rows where `v1 == 1`, and combine them as a single dataframe.

How could I do that in R?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Try `df[c(sample(which(df$v1==0),5000),sample(which(df$v1==1),5000)),]`

Comment: It's great. Thank you @nicola

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by `which`

```
a <- df[sample(which( df$v1 == 0 ),5000 ),]
b <- df[sample(which( df$v1 == 1 ),5000 ),]
rbind(a,b)
```